# Timber, Twig, and Woocommerce: Last product stays in the cart after checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am building a site in timber that uses Woocommerce. Everything is working great, except I can't get products out of the cart.

I'm using Woocommerce Product Add-ons, a subscription plugin called Subscriptio, and some custom Woocommerce functions. however, when I disable all of these, I still can't get the cart to empty after a successful checkout. I have isolated the problem to Timber.

I can create an extremely simple page.php template, that isn't using twig, like so:

`<?
get_header();
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
get_footer(); ?>`

And when Wordpress uses this template, the cart empties just fine. But when I serve the page using twig, the very last item added to the shopping cart stays in there, so when I pay, then go back to the cart, there's always one item left in it.

The header and footer invoked in the above example just point to twig templates, so it's something about just that twig page template that causes the problem.

Does anyone know what could be going on here, and now to fix it?